# How do I use WS-Addressing in WCF and set the wsa:replyto header?

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, soap, ws-addressing

I'm calling a BizTalk service using WCF. The service requires the wsa:replyto address to be set in the SOAP header to able to make a 'callback' when the process is done.

We are using a contract-first approch with auto-generated code from svcutil (we cannot 'just' change the contract)...

And it's not possible to do in the config file...

I have seen someone 'overriding' some methods to make their own custom header - but this is not a custom header it's a standard in the SOAP protocol.

How can I add the wsa:replyto in the (SOAP) header?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In order to invoke a service that requires [WS-Addressing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Addressing) from WCF you'll have to configure the client endpoint to use a binding that supports it, such as the [WSHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding.aspx).

You can then set the `wsa:ReplyTo` header to a specific URL in your client code through the [OperationContext.OutgoingMessageHeaders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.outgoingmessageheaders.aspx) property:

```
using (new OperationContextScope((IContextChannel)channel))
{
    OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.ReplyTo =
        new EndpointAddress("http://client/callback");

    channel.DoSomething();
}
```

In this example we are setting the `wsa:ReplyTo` header to a known URL where the client channel listens for incoming callback messages from the service.

Alternatively, *if the service supports it*, you could use the [WSDualHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.aspx), which has built in support for **duplex communication** through WS-Addressing. In this case you would set the callback address through the [WSDualHttpBinding.ClientBaseAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.wsdualhttpbinding.clientbaseaddress.aspx) property:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsDualHttpBinding>
            <binding clientBaseAddress="http://client/callback" />
        </wsDualHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://server/service"
                  binding="wsDualHttpBinding"
                  contract="Namespace.Service" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: I found a solution which were much more complex than yours... Your solution is nice, easy and clean... Thanks!

Comment: I'm using a Custom Binding, so had to set --> <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />