# SOAP WCF WS-Addressing 'Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none' found.'

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, ws-addressing

I'm working on a Client that communicate with a legacy system utilizing SOAP WCF WS-Addressing messages.

Additionally, its required to customize the SOAP-Envelope header with `To` and `Action` headers that contains custom information.

I was able to set the `To` and `Action` SOAP-Envelope header with the information through utilizing the `OperationContextScope` as shown in the code below:

```
public async Task<getAttorneyResponseStructure> GetAttorneyAsync(GetAttorneyRequestStructure getAttorneyRequestStructure)
{
  try
  {
    using (new OperationContextScope(Client.InnerChannel))
    {
      getAttorneyRequestStructure.AttorneyHeader = Header;

      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.To = new Uri("http://rydwvgsn01.spga.gov.sa/GSBExpress/Legal/MOJAttorneyInquiry/2.0/AttorneyInquiryService.svc");

      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Action = "http://tempuri.org/IAttorneyInquiryService/GetAttorney";

      return await Client.GetAttorneyAsync(getAttorneyRequestStructure);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   throw;
  }
}
```

When I run the code and try to send the message I end up with the an exception `Multiple headers with name 'Action' and namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none' found.`

By looking at the exception stack as attached in the picture, it seems there is an object containing the same information of the header that I'm trying to add.

[image]

So, my question is there a work around changing the Namespace of the `Action` header or modify the existing `Action` that containing the set Namespace?

Comment: You can read these articles to find the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129750/how-do-i-use-ws-addressing-in-wcf-and-set-the-wsareplyto-header and 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.operationcontextscope?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: I've actually followed these links in writing the solution. The problem I'm facing is that apparently there are 2 headers with `Action` in the request and it happens they have the same `namespace`. What I'm trying to find is how to change these namespaces for any of those headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
It turned out that the issue I was using the default `BasicHttpBinding` that was using different soap version different from the server. Additionally, `Action` attribute in the header wasn't needed since I've changed SOAP version using `CustomBinding` as follow in the connection constructor:

```
CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding();

var mtomMessageEncodingBindingElement = new MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement
{
  MessageVersion = MessageVersion.CreateVersion(EnvelopeVersion.Soap11, AddressingVersion.WSAddressing10),
};
binding.Elements.Add(mtomMessageEncodingBindingElement);

var httpTransportBindingElement = new HttpTransportBindingElement();
binding.Elements.Add(httpTransportBindingElement);
            
Client = new AttorneyInquiryServiceClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("http://rydwvgsn01.spga.gov.sa/GSBExpress/Legal/MOJAttorneyInquiry/2.0/AttorneyInquiryService.svc"));
```

Some additional explanation for the code above:

- `MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement`: Was used to be able to set the version of the SOAP version and to enable MOTM type of response.
- `HttpTransportBindingElement`: Is needed in the Binding.
- In the method calling, `Action` was removed.

```
public async Task<getAttorneyResponseStructure> GetAttorneyAsync(GetAttorneyRequestStructure getAttorneyRequestStructure)
{
  try
  {
    using (new OperationContextScope(Client.InnerChannel))
    {
      getAttorneyRequestStructure.AttorneyHeader = Header;

      OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.To = new Uri("http://rydwvgsn01.spga.gov.sa/GSBExpress/Legal/MOJAttorneyInquiry/2.0/AttorneyInquiryService.svc");

      return await Client.GetAttorneyAsync(getAttorneyRequestStructure);
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   throw;
  }
}
```